# долгая выгрузка файла с urllib

Tags: python, urllib

Добрый день,

Выгружаю картинки по ссылкам (с помощью urllib). Делаю это так:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Думаю, что ответ приходит сразу, но функция urlopen не отдает управление еще минуты две. Если ограничить таймаут, то все начинает работать (но фиксированный таймаут это не очень хорошо, т.к он не отдает управление до конца таймаута).
Видимо питон выходить из urlopen после потери соединения с сервером.

Пробовал генерировать и парсить http загаловки и напрямую пихать в сокет, это работает, но хотелось бы разобраться почему urllib так себе ведет.

UDP:
Посмотрел снифером, данные загружаются и сервер отвечает 200 ОК где-то за 0.1 секунду, но urllib не отдает управление

Спасибо!

Comment: Если вы Ctrl+C нажмёте в течение двух минут, то какой traceback получается? Что значит "ответ приходит сразу"? Вы уверены сервер throttle не включает, к примеру, на основе User-Agent? (спасёт только от copy-paste)

Comment: @jfs спасибо за ответ! Если нажать Ctrl+C, то видно что sock.connect(sa) блокирует исполнение. User-Agent пробовал подсовывать свой. Заметил, что не со всеми серверами такая проблема наблюдается (правда, к примеру, браузер нормально грузит)

Comment: пробовали по IP обращаться? или руками getaddrinfo вызывать?

Comment: @jfs когда напрямую через сокет отправлял запросы, то через ip общался, но urllib вроде символические ссылки принимает

Comment: вы можете ip передать в urllib и увидеть что задержка меньше будет. Суть в том что, определяя ip (и другие параметры для соединения) несколько вариантов, возвращаемых getaddrinfo, может проверяться по очереди (каждый со своим timeout). https://stackoverflow.com/a/28674109/4279

Comment: @jfs к сожалению, по времени ничего не поменялось

Comment: какой точно код использовался? как время измерялось? обновите вопрос.

Comment: @jfs осмотрел снифером, данные загружаются и сервер отвечает 200 ОК где-то за 0.1 секунду, но urllib не отдает управление. либа что-то делает оставшейся время

Comment: как сервер может 200 OK вернуть, когда вы говорите у вас код на connect() вызове висит?

Comment: @jfs да, висит, 2минуты (если самому таймаут не устанавливать), а потом возвращает ответ

Comment: не может быть, чтобы одновременно код на connect  две минуты висел, когда вы говорите, что 200 OK через 0.1 секунд возвращается (который только после возвращения connect(), после отсылки запроса клиентом, после ответа сервера может появиться).

Comment: @jfs Да, вы правы. Ерунда выходит, видимо не туда посмотрел снифером. Лвиная доля времени уходит на коннект ipv6 адреса выходит (засунул принс прям в код либы)

Comment: `ip, port = socket.getaddrinfo(host, 80, family=socket.AF_INET))[0][-1]; urlopen(f'http://{ip}:{port}/path?query=1')` чтобы по ipv4 обращаться

Comment: @jfs Спасибо большое!